# PHP multiple clients accessing same file

Tags: php, hitcounter

I started playing with PHP, and saw this code snippet that is supposed to act a hit counter for a webpage:

```
/* counter */

//opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits
$datei = fopen("/countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count=$count + 1 ;
echo "$count" ;
echo " hits" ;
echo "\n" ;

// opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$datei = fopen("/countlog.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);
```

Based on what I read, multiple requests can run simultaneously on the server. So there is chance that they access this file `countlog.txt` at the same time (correct?). If so, this code doesn't work for a busy website (correct?). How would one change this code to make it work for a busy website? Can you use locks in PHP that is shared between multiple request?

PS: The question is NOT about counters. Please avoid using SQL in the answer if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flock() to get an exclusive lock on a file, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    $datei = fopen("/countlog.txt","r");
    $count = fgets($datei,1000);

    $count=$count + 1 ;
    echo "$count" ;
    echo " hits" ;
    echo "\n" ;

    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $count);
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    echo "Could not lock file!";
}

fclose($fp);
```

Maybe you should build a loop that waits for a successfull lock using usleep() to avoid active waiting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php

Comment: According to the docs, flock will block until the lock is acquired. Why do you suggest using a loop (assuming a while loop)?

Comment: Sorry, did not mention this: I usually use flock() with Option LOCK_NB. This gives me opportunity to avoid deadlocks. E.g. one could only try to aquire the lock 100 times and then give up.

Answer (score 3):

I think your requirement should be implemented considering your traffic.

If your traffic is low, implementing lock based counter couldn’t be a issue. Because probability of concurrent access to a same file is very low and it takes few milliseconds to open, write and close the file.

Another solution could be using a memcached, redis or APC caching mechanism and keep a single counter in a key store.

If you are considering few million hits per second, it couldn't be hosted in a single server. Most probably it is scaled with a load balancer and hosted in different regions/servers. Then a hit counter should be implemented non blocked service like a messaging queue. If you interested about queuing your hit counter you can read more on [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html), or [activemq](http://activemq.apache.org/)

RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ supports following protocols and many other protocols and you can find many php client libraries to connect over those protocols.

- AMQP - [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib),
- Stomp - [reactphp/stomp](https://github.com/reactphp/stomp), [stomp-php](https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php), [ZendQueue](http://ZendQueue)

**Few code samples**

**Using APC as counter**

```
<?php
apc_add('counter', 0);
echo apc_inc('counter')
?>
```

**Using Memcached**

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$m->add('counter', 0);
$m->increment('counter');
?>
```

**RabbitMQ and php-amqplib**

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "videlalvaro/php-amqplib": "2.5.*"
    }
}

$ composer.phar install

<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('counter', false, false, false, false);

$callback = function($msg) {
  // $msg->body has the content of the message
  // counter update implementation goes here
};

$channel->basic_consume('counter', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
?>
```